# [Vue warn]: Property or method "messages" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: laravel-5.3, vue-component, laravel-5.4

I'm testing VueJs for testing purpose where user will send some message and message will be render to homepage through components.

Here I have used three components ..But when I send the message I see the following message..on console :

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "messages" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render.
>
> [Vue warn]: Property or method "addMessage" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive
>   data properties in the data option.

Here is the blade page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Chatroom</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <h1>Chatroom</h1>
            <chat-log :messages="messages"></chat-log>
            <chat-composer v-on:messagesent="addMessage"></chat-composer>
        </div>
        <script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the `ChatMessage.vue` components:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="chat-message">
    <p>{{ message.message }}</p>
    <small>{{ message.user }}</small>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['message']
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
.chat-message {
    padding: 1rem;
}
.chat-message > p {
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
```

ChatLog.vue

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="chat-log">
      <chat-message v-for="message in messages" :message="message"></chat-message>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['messages']
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
.chat-log .chat-message:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

ChatComposer.vue

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="chat-composer">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Start typing your message..." v-model="messageText" @keyup.enter="sendMessage">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="sendMessage">Send</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            messageText: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendMessage() {
            this.$emit('messagesent', {
                message: this.messageText,
                user: "John Doe"
            });
            this.messageText = '';
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
.chat-composer {
    display: flex;
}
.chat-composer input {
    flex: 1 auto;
}
.chat-composer button {
    border-radius: 0;
}
</style>
```

app.js (main vue js file)

```
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

Vue.component('chat-message', require('./components/ChatMessage.vue'));
Vue.component('chat-log', require('./components/ChatLog.vue'));
Vue.component('chat-composer', require('./components/ChatComposer.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        messages: [
            {
                message: 'Hey!',
                user: "John Doe"
            },
            {
                message: 'Hello!',
                user: "Jane Doe"
            }
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        addMessage(message) {
            // Add to existing messages
            this.messages.push(message);
            // Persist to the database etc
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show your actual Vue instance as well?

Comment: I added with the code..check it once please

Comment: I've just set up a new project with all the code from above and didn't get any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `chat-log` and `chat-composer` components are referenced in the main html page, the data you send to them has to be inside the main Vue instance.

`messages` that you send as a prop as well as the `addMessage` method that you want to be a listener that will notify the main instance when messages are sent have to be inside the main vue js instance (root)

```
new Vue({
//your code
data:{
 messages:[]//populate it with some data
},
methods:{
  addMessage(message){
   //this will get called when chat composer calls sendMessage
  }
}
})
```